# How the command is completed view the menu back?

Tags: bash

How the command is completed (restart apache or mysql) view the menu back?

```
 VALUE=$(dialog --default-item "2" --stdout --menu "MENU" 50 160 50\
      "1" "Test-1" \
      "2" "Test-2")

 case $VALUE in
      1) /etc/init.d/apache2 restart 2>&1 | dialog --progressbox 16 80; sleep 1; ?????;;
      2) /etc/init.d/mysql restart 2>&1 | dialog --progressbox 16 80; sleep 1; ?????;;
 esac
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the code you posted in a `while` loop and add a "quit" option that executes `break`.

```
while :

    VALUE=$(dialog --default-item "2" --stdout --menu "MENU" 50 160 50\
          "1" "Test-1" \
          "2" "Test-2" \
          "3" "quit")

    case $VALUE in
        1) /etc/init.d/apache2 restart 2>&1 | dialog --progressbox 16 80; sleep 1;;
        2) /etc/init.d/mysql restart 2>&1 | dialog --progressbox 16 80; sleep 1;;
        3) break;;
    esac

done
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I counseled a better solution to use "--progressbox" for display in a new window or directly
in dialog under menu (down).